# SharePoint Server 15 Wish List

Tags: 2013

SharePoint Server 2010 is a fantastic product! However, I'm sure you have some great ideas for v.Next.

**What features do you believe could be improved for SharePoint 15?**

One topic per answer please (you can leave multiple answers) so the community can vote.

<sub>(Question inspired by [Project 15 Wish List](http://epmsource.com/2010/03/15/project-15-feature-wish-list/) post.)</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure this will make it to anyone else in the product team, and I can't promise I'll check back.

Feel free to send suggestions to me directly: kevin.davis@microsoft.com

Answer (score 2):

My biggest wish list item is to have all persisted data exposed through the APIs in a consistent way.  While most of the social data is available, you do not interact with it in the same way you do with the regular lists.  There is no easy way to get a collection of user profiles for example.

Next I would like to see additional accelerators and modules offered up between cycles.  The Infrastructure Updates and Admin toolkit are a good example of that.  I think the Service Applications framework could support this as well.

Comment: be also great to be able to get the Most Recent Rated content without having to iterate over every single user profile in the Service Aplication ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First thing i want is better debugging facility in Content Deployment.

Answer (score 1):

A better WYSIWIG Content Editor which can support full Copy Paste (including images). Images can be saved in image library automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Make InfoPath Services part of SharePoint Foundation (free)

Answer (score 0):

Where's my easy button?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I was being facetious.